# HTML table rows not counted in IE, Work well in Chrome/FF , for Pagination using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Web application using jQuery, I want to add pagination. It works well on Firefox & Chrome. But on IE 8 it can't calculate the number of rows.

```
this.init = function () {
    var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
    var records = (rows.length);
    this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
    this.inited = true;
}
```

rows returning 0 in IE 8 but all other browser giving correct row count.

I am appending the html table to DIV
Following is the html created of my table

```
<TABLE style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-TOP:     5px" class="pad white" border=0 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1 width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD bgColor=#0f4d79 width="10%">
<DIV align=center><STRONG>#</STRONG></DIV></TD>
<TD bgColor=#0f4d79 width="10%">
<DIV align=center><STRONG>Date</STRONG></DIV></TD>
<TD bgColor=#0f4d79 width="20%">
<DIV align=center><STRONG>Customer</STRONG></DIV></TD>
<TD bgColor=#0f4d79 width="30%">
<DIV align=center><STRONG>Description</STRONG></DIV></TD>
<TD bgColor=#0f4d79 width="10%">
<DIV align=center><STRONG>Status</STRONG></DIV></TD>
<TD bgColor=#0f4d79 width="20%">
<DIV align=center><STRONG>Amount</STRONG></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<DIV class=border-middle>
<TABLE id=**tblIncomeListData** class=pad border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0        width="100%">
<TR class=even jQuery172016229059503345766="72">
<TD style="DISPLAY: none" vAlign=top width=0% align=middle>30</TD>
<TD vAlign=top width="10%" align=middle>00001</TD>
<TD vAlign=top width="10%" align=middle>May 28, 2013</TD>
<TD vAlign=top width="20%" align=middle>test1</TD>
<TD vAlign=top width="30%" align=middle>Other Income </TD>
<TD vAlign=top width="10%" align=middle>Paid</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top width="20%">OMR444.00</TD></TR></TABLE></DIV>
```

Comment: Works for me in IE8: http://jsbin.com/ocufuf/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/ocufuf/1/edit), both in standard view and (in)compatible view. Please create a [small, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem and post it to your question (and optionally also to a place like http://jsbin.com or http://jsFiddle.net).

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant `javascript-events` and `jquery-ajax` tags from your question. Please be sure only to include *relevant* tags.

Comment: Ok, I will keep in mind next time.

Comment: @ Constant: I didn't mean next time. Your question, as it stands, can't be answered because what you've shown doesn't do what you've said it does. Not a problem, just fix it with the "edit" link, and people will be happy to try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd, I thought IE8 supported the `rows` property. *(Edit: It does: http://jsbin.com/ocufuf/1 Still, I'll leave this in place for now...)*

Unless you have a table nested within that table (and it doesn't look like you do), you can replace it with `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Or of course, with jQuery (since you say you're using it, although it's not apparent from your code samples):

```
var rows = $("#" + tableName + " tr");
```

Note that if you do that, you'll have to change your table name, as `**tblIncomeListData**` is a valid `id` for HTML, but not for CSS.

If you were doing nested tables, you could still get the count easily with jQuery:

```
var rows = $("#" + tableName).children('thead, tbody, tfoot').children('tr');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like charm..                                    var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).getElementsByTagName('tr');

Comment: @ConstantLearner: Huh. Well, glad it helped! I wonder what the problem with `rows` is, though, it's been supported by basically everything for years...

Comment: Yes, I am totally agree but somehow it does not work on IE8 in my case, Now i change & it work on all browser. Thanks again..!!

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById(table).getElementsByTagName("tr").length

Comment: The .length part you added is important because we want to count tr elements, not just return them. The above contributors forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery, use the following code for getting the number of rows.

```
var rows = $('#tableId tr').length;
```

Also note that  after getElementById, you have used tableName variable.

Don't know if you are storing the id of the table in that variable but ideally the ID of the table element has to be passed if you are using `getElementById` or `#tableId`.
Hope this would help.

Comment: Yes I am passing tablename also, it works in FF/Chrome but not in IE8 May Be due to it does not get that table because it is inside div.